# How can I be notified when the Ec2 itself is modified

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I was trying to get a notification, it doesn't matter how as though via email, sms, etc. The notification shouldn't be for state-changes only,  which I have already done. Instead, I'd like to be notified when a EIP is disassociated, either network interface or volume is detached, or something bearing on affecting the Ec2 itself.

Is this possible?

I have been working with Amazon EventBridge rules, but I only get captured when is stopped, terminated or running.

Comment: Yes, its possible through AWS Config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'd like to be notified when a EIP is disassociated, either network interface or volume is detached, or something bearing on affecting the Ec2 itself.

If you want to be notified of a *specific* event, such as when an EIP is disassociated, I would recommend you use EventBridge with a CloudTrail pattern (in this case, for the `DisassociateAddress` event).

If you want to be notified of *any* changes to the EC2 instance, I would recommend you use Config.

Comment: This is my Event pattern @paolo; however, I added the instance-id to get that instance's changes only but didn't work. I had to remove it, and I am getting now alerts for all my Ec2s.

Is it possible to narrow it to one instance only, or should I go for AWS Config?

`{
  "source": ["aws.ec2"],
  "detail-type": ["AWS API Call via CloudTrail"],
  "detail": {
    "instance-id": ["i-090037f8fd368ffff"]
    "eventSource": ["ec2.amazonaws.com"],
    "eventName": ["AssociateAddress", "AllocateAddress", "DisassociateAddress"]
  }
}`

Comment: @FaustoGomez yes it is possible. Find the event from cloudtrail and try and match it in the EventBridge pattern editor

Answer (score 1):

So, I figured it out as you said it @paolo. Basically, I have looked for the event on CloudTrail, and match it on Eventbridge; however, I had to do all the Event Patterns separately as follows to make them work.

For the detach network which is attach to the instance I want to monitor:

```
{
"source": ["aws.ec2"],
"detail-type": ["AWS API Call via CloudTrail"],
"detail": {
    "eventSource": ["ec2.amazonaws.com"],
    "eventName": ["DetachNetworkInterface"],
    "requestParameters": {"attachmentId": ["eni-attach-0671ffxxx10bxxx46"]}
}
```

And for the instance status

```
{
"source": ["aws.ec2"],
"detail-type": ["AWS API Call via CloudTrail"],
"detail": {
    "eventSource": ["ec2.amazonaws.com"],
    "eventName": [
        "RunInstances",
        "StartInstances",
        "StopInstances",
        "TerminateInstances"
    ],
    "requestParameters": {
        "instancesSet": {
            "items": {"instanceId": ["i-09513xxxd3xxxa04"]}
        }
    }
}
```

And so on for AIM roles, DetachVolumes, ModifyNetworkInterface, etc.